# Document / log all events affecting product?

Tags: project-management

I have no idea if i'm asking this on the correct place. But i want to log events for a product / website so we always have a backlog and can go back and see what has happened on a high level. It could be stuff like:

- Code deployed (grab from github releases)
- Google changed something that could affect SEO (maybe import from GA analytics)
- Sudden change in traffic (maybe from GA as well, or manual)
- We changed title on page X
- Custom event like 'Hosting were down for 10 minutes'

And so on, of course i want dates on these and maybe some more meta info. Not sure if you understand what im looking for but it's really simple and i could build something myself but i figured it might be common that companies would want something like this. Anyone know what this might be called? I have tried to search for stuff like "Log events" and "Product journal" and what not but i have no idea what this is even called.

Well, this question was kind of vague but would be really helpful if someone could even suggest some google searches i could do to maybe find what i want.

Comment: @mokubai Can you recommend any stack exchange site this might be more relevant for?

Comment: You've brought it mostly on topic here, but if you have requirements specifically for a tool to solve your problem then there is [softwarerecs.se]